# Cant compile uwsgi under centos (fc10) with python2.6

Tags: python, compilation, wsgi, uwsgi

it`s normally build with python 2.5 BUT i need 2.6!
2.6 normally installed in /opt/python26 and successfully run as python2.6 in console.

but

```
python2.6 uwsgiconfig.py --build
```

give me

```
*** uWSGI linking ***
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/somepath/" python2.6 uwsgiconfig.py --build
```

where `somepath` is the path to your `libpython2.6.so.x` file.

Respectively update your `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and add the path to the libraries and run `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit uwsgiconfig.py and set PYLIB_PATH to the path of the python lib directory.